# C#: throwing exception Value cannot be null for list<int>

Tags: c#

Test function returning null when user input is 10. please guide me how to handle this situation

```
List<int?> test10 = testInt(9, 10).ToList();

public static List<int?> testInt(int pagetotal, int userinput)
{
    List<int?> _data = null;

    if (userinput <= 10 && userinput != 0)
    {
        if (userinput <= pagetotal)
        {
            _data = Enumerable.Repeat(pagetotal / userinput, userinput - 1).ToList();
            int y = (pagetotal - pagetotal / userinput * (userinput - 1));
            _data.Add(y);

        }
    }

    return _data;
}
```

Comment: For starters, if you are already returning a `List` there is no need to call `ToList` on it :)  Secondly, if your `userinput` value is 11+ or 0, or it is > `pagetotal` you are returning `null`. I am pretty sure this is causing your `null` issue. In your example you are calling this with `pagetotal=9` and `userinput=10`, which leads to a null return based on your if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_data` is set to a non-`null` value only when all these conditions are `true`:

- `userinput <= 10` - this is `true`, because `userinput` is `10`
- `userinput != 0` - this is `true`, because `userinput` is `10`
- `userinput <= pagetotal` - this is `false`, because `userinput` is `10` while `pagetotal` is `9`

You need to decide what to return when `pagetotal` is less than `userinput`. Currently it is `null`, but you could potentially return an empty list:

```
if (userinput <= pagetotal) {
    ...
} else {
    _data = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userinput <= pagetotal
```

That part prevents _data from being initialized if userinput >=10 (with pageTotal=9).
I think it is better to normalize userinput first.
You can add following line:

```
if(userInput > total)
    userInput = total;
if(userInput <1)
    userInput =1;
```